# SQL join 3 table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, left-join

i m using SQL 2008 R2

i got duplicate value from my join table:
[image: Join Table]

```
SELECT *
FROM LETTRE_VOIT 
 LEFT JOIN FAWEB_CLIENT ON FAWEB_CLIENT.CODE_CLIENT = LETTRE_VOIT.CODE_CLIENT
 LEFT  JOIN ORDRE ON ORDRE.CODE_DEST = LETTRE_VOIT.CODE_DEST AND ORDRE.CODE_CLIENT = LETTRE_VOIT.CODE_CLIENT
   AND ORDRE.DATE_CLOTUR = LETTRE_VOIT.DATE_CLOTURE
WHERE  LETTRE_VOIT.NO_ORDRE IN ('5530','5533')
```

as you can see on image i got double value of 5530 and 5533.

my table FAWEB_CLIENT with ID Code_Client 
table LETTRE_VOIT with ID NOID and NO_ORDRE
table ORDRE with ID NO_ORDRE and NO_CLIENT

i can not use DISTINCT:
[image: Distinct]
 error message:  The text data type can not be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable

Comment: why can't you use `DISTINCT`?

Comment: The text data type can not be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable

Comment: Can you copy the query into the question, as text?  It is easier to read as a screen shot and easier to modify for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that your joins are not correct.  My suspicion is that you are missing a join condition on `Letter_Voit.No_Ordre`:

```
SELECT *
FROM LETTRE_VOIT 
 LEFT JOIN FAWEB_CLIENT ON FAWEB_CLIENT.CODE_CLIENT = LETTRE_VOIT.CODE_CLIENT
 LEFT  JOIN ORDRE ON ORDRE.CODE_DEST = LETTRE_VOIT.CODE_DEST AND ORDRE.CODE_CLIENT = LETTRE_VOIT.CODE_CLIENT
   AND ORDRE.DATE_CLOTUR = LETTRE_VOIT.DATE_CLOTURE and
   LETTRE_VOIT.No_ORDRE = Order.No_ORDRE
WHERE  LETTRE_VOIT.NO_ORDRE IN ('5530','5533')
```

You may be able to remove some of the other join conditions, which may become redundant.